# Which annotations are baked in to Java?

Tags: java, annotations

I was looking for a list of annotations in Java that have some meaningful use and are enabled by default (without having to import anything). For example, @Deprecated, @SuppressWarning, etc. I couldn't find one though. Is it out there somewhere, or could we compile one?

Comment: Did you happen to look at the [annotations documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) by Sun/Oracle?

Comment: Anything in java.lang doesn't require importing, regardless of the type (annotation, interface or class), everything else requires importing.

Comment: Sun doesn't have SafeVarArgs or the annotations that apply to annotations. So it's incomplete.

Comment: @smcg - Because the documentation was for Java 6. SafeVarargs is the only new annotations in `java.lang` in Java 7.

Comment: I did look at it and I didn't trust that it was complete. And it wasn't. That's why I didn't consider it an acceptable source.

Comment: @smog It is not only an 'acceptable source' but the *definitive* source. You looked at the wrong version, so you should have looked at the right version. Compared to that, anything you get here is just opinion: certainly not a more 'acceptable' source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Annotations in `java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) (not requiring additional import) package available in standard JDK include:

- [`@Deprecated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

  > A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.
- [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

  > Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a supertype.
- [`@SuppressWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)

  > Indicates that the named compiler warnings should be suppressed in the annotated element (and in all program elements contained in the annotated element).
- [`@SafeVarargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) (since Java 7)

  > A programmer assertion that the body of the annotated method or constructor does not perform potentially unsafe operations on its varargs parameter.

Don't forget to check out [`java.lang.annotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/package-summary.html) and [`javax.annotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/package-summary.html) packages.

Comment: Should note that SafeVarargs is Java7 and newer only.

Answer (score 0):

First Bing result: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly these 3 annotation,

```
@Deprecated
@Override
@SuppressWarnings
```

But from Java 7 below was also included.

```
@SafeVarargs
```

**See these links below:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html